# Why GCC not use more register when compiling C code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

When compiling C code on Ubuntu using cross platform GCC for ARM CPU, for each assembly instruction, the source data will be loaded from stack and the result will be written to stack. Why GCC not use more registers to reduce the time in load/store data?
Is it that because ARM is load and store structure, GCC will use load/store for the data of each assembly instruction?

The following is my bubble sort function:

```
bool bubble_sort(int* data, int dataSize) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int dataTmp;

    for(i=0; i<dataSize-1; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<dataSize-1; j++) {
            if(data[j] > data[j+1]) {
                dataTmp = data[j+1];
                data[j+1] = data[j];
                data[j] = dataTmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The following is the assembly code compiled from the C code above using cross platform GCC tool on Ubuntu:

```
00008d0c <bubble_sort>:
    8d0c:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
    8d10:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
    8d14:   e24dd01c    sub sp, sp, #28
    8d18:   e50b0018    str r0, [fp, #-24]
    8d1c:   e50b101c    str r1, [fp, #-28]
    8d20:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
    8d24:   e50b3010    str r3, [fp, #-16]
    8d28:   ea000032    b   8df8 <bubble_sort+0xec>
    8d2c:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
    8d30:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
    8d34:   ea000027    b   8dd8 <bubble_sort+0xcc>
    8d38:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8d3c:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
    8d40:   e51b2018    ldr r2, [fp, #-24]
    8d44:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
    8d48:   e5932000    ldr r2, [r3]
    8d4c:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8d50:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
    8d54:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
    8d58:   e51b1018    ldr r1, [fp, #-24]
    8d5c:   e0813003    add r3, r1, r3
    8d60:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
    8d64:   e1520003    cmp r2, r3
    8d68:   da000017    ble 8dcc <bubble_sort+0xc0>
    8d6c:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8d70:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
    8d74:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
    8d78:   e51b2018    ldr r2, [fp, #-24]
    8d7c:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
    8d80:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
    8d84:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
    8d88:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8d8c:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
    8d90:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
    8d94:   e51b2018    ldr r2, [fp, #-24]
    8d98:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
    8d9c:   e51b200c    ldr r2, [fp, #-12]
    8da0:   e1a02102    lsl r2, r2, #2
    8da4:   e51b1018    ldr r1, [fp, #-24]
    8da8:   e0812002    add r2, r1, r2
    8dac:   e5922000    ldr r2, [r2]
    8db0:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
    8db4:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8db8:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
    8dbc:   e51b2018    ldr r2, [fp, #-24]
    8dc0:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
    8dc4:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
    8dc8:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
    8dcc:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8dd0:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
    8dd4:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
    8dd8:   e51b301c    ldr r3, [fp, #-28]
    8ddc:   e2432001    sub r2, r3, #1
    8de0:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8de4:   e1520003    cmp r2, r3
    8de8:   caffffd2    bgt 8d38 <bubble_sort+0x2c>
    8dec:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
    8df0:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
    8df4:   e50b3010    str r3, [fp, #-16]
    8df8:   e51b301c    ldr r3, [fp, #-28]
    8dfc:   e2432001    sub r2, r3, #1
    8e00:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
    8e04:   e1520003    cmp r2, r3
    8e08:   caffffc7    bgt 8d2c <bubble_sort+0x20>
    8e0c:   e3a03001    mov r3, #1
    8e10:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
    8e14:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
    8e18:   e8bd0800    ldmfd   sp!, {fp}
    8e1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

The following is the code I wrote using inline assembly to use more registers to reduce the time in load/store:

```
void bubble_sort(int *data, int size) {
    //r2 = i
    //r3 = j
    asm volatile(
"       STMDB SP!, {r0-r7}  \n\t"
"                               "
"       SUB r1, r1, #1      \n\t" // r3 = size-1
"       LSL r1, r1, #2      \n\t" // int
"                               "
"       MOV r2, #0          \n\t" // r2 = i = 0
"                               "
"loop1:                     \n\t"
"       CMP r2, r1          \n\t" // r2 == r3: i == size-1
"       BEQ loop_end        \n\t"  
"                               "
"       MOV r3, #0          \n\t" // r3 = j = 1
"       MOV r4, r0          \n\t" // r4 = data
"       ADD r5, r4, #4      \n\t" // r5 = data + 4
"                               "
"loop2:                     \n\t"
"       CMP r3, r1          \n\t" // r3 == r1: j==size
"       BEQ loop1_end       \n\t"  
"                               "
"       LDR r6, [r4], #0    \n\t" //data[j-1]
"       LDR r7, [r5], #0    \n\t" //data[j]
"       CMP r6, r7          \n\t"
"       BLE incr_addr       \n\t"
"                               "
"       STR r6, [r5], #4    \n\t" //swp data, address + 4
"       STR r7, [r4], #4    \n\t"
"       B   loop2_end       \n\t"
"                               "
"incr_addr:                 \n\t"
"       ADD r4, r4, #4      \n\t" // r4 = r4 + 4
"       ADD r5, r5, #4      \n\t" // r5 = r5 + 4
"                               "
"loop2_end:                 \n\t"
"       ADD r3, r3, #4      \n\t"
"       B   loop2           \n\t"
"                               "
"loop1_end:                 \n\t"
"       ADD r2, r2, #4      \n\t"
"       B   loop1           \n\t"
"                               "
"loop_end:                  \n\t"
"                               "
"       LDMIA SP!,{r0-r7}       "
    );
    //back to caller
    //"      BX   lr              "
}
```

Comment: And this was compiled -O what with what other command options?  BTW, a 2% increase in memory usage speed is wiped out by the fact you are using a O(N^2) sort...

Comment: Have you tried different optimization options?

Comment: That's `-O0` code. Even on `-O1` that whole function compiles to 21 instructions (using a Linaro 13.11 build of GCC 4.8.3). In my experience, if you mention anything about how stupid unoptimised assembly output looks to a GCC engineer, you get the response "well, what did you expect?" and a withering stare of disapproval.

Comment: ...not to mention, as Michael points out, the hilariously laughable exercise of optimizing a bubblesort. Like putting a spoiler on a golf cart.

Comment: I didn't try different optimization options. I'll try later. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use optimization -O3, gcc will use more registers.

```
00008e10 <bubble_sort>:
    8e10:   e92d0030    push    {r4, r5}
    8e14:   e2414001    sub r4, r1, #1
    8e18:   e3540000    cmp r4, #0
    8e1c:   da00000d    ble 8e58 <bubble_sort+0x48>
    8e20:   e080c101    add ip, r0, r1, lsl #2
    8e24:   e2805004    add r5, r0, #4
    8e28:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
    8e2c:   e1a03005    mov r3, r5
    8e30:   e5131004    ldr r1, [r3, #-4]
    8e34:   e4932004    ldr r2, [r3], #4
    8e38:   e1510002    cmp r1, r2
    8e3c:   c5031004    strgt   r1, [r3, #-4]
    8e40:   c5032008    strgt   r2, [r3, #-8]
    8e44:   e153000c    cmp r3, ip
    8e48:   1afffff8    bne 8e30 <bubble_sort+0x20>
    8e4c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
    8e50:   e1500004    cmp r0, r4
    8e54:   1afffff4    bne 8e2c <bubble_sort+0x1c>
    8e58:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
    8e5c:   e8bd0030    pop {r4, r5}
    8e60:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```